# Create a new column to a dataframe based on the values of another dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
name
Google
Amazon
Google
Yahoo
Google
Yahoo
```

And another one like this:

```
name   stock_name
Google  stockA
Amazon  stockB
Yahoo   stockC
```

The final result I would like to take from the merge of these 2 dataframes:

```
name stock_name
Google stockA
Amazon stockB
Google stockA
Yahoo  stockC
Google stockA
Yahoo  stockC
```

Using the merge it is not possible to make it. Any hind on how could make it?

Comment: Huh? Why is a merge not possible?

Comment: Unless a valid reason is given, this is 100% duplicate of merge post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871

Comment: @MrFlick you believe right outer join is the solution?

Comment: Well, possibly left outer join depending on your ordering but yes. This is the most basic of merge operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you call your data frames df1 and df2 you could do

```
 df1$stock_name <- df2$stock_name[match(df1$name, df2$name)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(data = c("Google", "Amazon", "Google", "Yahoo", "Google", "Yahoo"))

df2 <- data.frame(data = c("Google" = "stockA", "Amazon"  = "stockB", "Yahoo" = "stockC"))
colnames(df2) <- "stock_name"

df1$stock_name <- df2[df1$data, 1]
```